# LyX to LaTeX conversion issue with [Figure] and [Subfigure]

Tags: floats, errors, lyx, subfloats

I am going back and forth between LaTeX and LyX.

I use TeXworks on WIndows 10 and have LyX 2.3 installed.

The major problem stems from using Figure and Subfigure (please see the codes below).

I tried everything to eliminate any extra packages that would make this conversion unnecessarily burdensome.

But I still have one problem with Figures and Subfigures.

When I export a LyX file to LaTeX(pdflatex), I get an error message here when compiling on TeXWorks:

> \begin{figure}[hp]
> \centering \captionsetup{justification=centering}
> \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth} \centering \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,bb = 0 0 200 100, draft, type=eps]{sample.png}

So what I do is get rid of the following,

> ,bb = 0 0 200 100, draft, type=eps

And, I run the following, and it compiles on TeXworks fine.

> \begin{figure}[hp]
> \centering \captionsetup{justification=centering}
> \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth} \centering \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{sample.png}

Question (1) Why do I need to do this every time I export from LyX to LaTeX(pdflatex)? Is there a way around this?

I have one other question when I do vice versa.
Now, I am trying to import a TeXworks file to LyX, but I also have a trouble with a similar Figure and Subfigure set-up.

The error message I get in LyX is:

> LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in sample.png (no spe...)

So, when I trace back to where this code is in Texworks file, I notice I coded as:

> \begin{figure}[hp]
> \centering
> \captionsetup{justification=centering}
> \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth} \centering \captionsetup{justification=centering}
> \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{sample1.jpg}
> \caption{sample1}
> \label{fig:sapmle1} \end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
> \centering \captionsetup{justification=centering} \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{sample.png}
> \caption{sample}
> \label{fig:sample} \end{subfigure}\caption{sample 1 and sample}
> \label{fig:samples}
> \end{figure}

I do not understand why this is giving the size problem in LyX when I import this.

Question (2) Can someone help me this issue when I import a LaTeX file to LyX? I import as LaTeX(plain).

Thanks!

*** Error Image Added ***
[image: a sample error message from LyX]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am going back and forth between LaTeX and LyX.

Definitely a bad idea. Marry with LyX or TeXworks, whichever you like the most, or follow a LyX > LaTeX workflow, but without going back.

> `\includegraphics[ ... , type=eps]{sample.png}`

Indeed, a PNG image should not have a `type=eps` option. Moreover, it should not show the extension `.png`, that is, even if you write  `sample.png` as filename in the image configuration dialogue, the output should be:

`\includegraphics[ ...]{sample}`

In Lyx,  I am able to produce the `type=eps` option only providing a fake image filename or including the above code for the image in a ERT (evil text red) box (Ctrl+L). Therefore, you should investigate why the image appear in LaTeX code as  `sample.png` (with the extension). I would check first if `sample.png` really is in the working directory, if the extension is correct, specially if there is not a hide extension (I think that it is still the horrible default in Windows, so an apparent `sample.png` in the file manager could be really `sample.png.exe` or `sample.png.eps`), etc.

Comment: Fran, thanks for the response! I will try it without .png extension. But how about when I have a few images with .jpg extension? Don't I need to specify this extension in such case?

Comment: @FrankSwanton  For pdflatex you can always suppress the .png,  .jpg or .pdf extension,  except if you have duplicate names with different extensions (e.g.,   foo.png, foo.jpg and foo.pdf)  and then you have to specify which one must be used.  Otherwise, LaTeX will search for any usable extension in a default order (that you can change, for instance, with` \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg, .png}` to use first the  JPG versions as first option and not use PDF versions).

Comment: Fran, this is excellent. Thank you!

Comment: Fran, so do you think when I convert LaTeX from TeXworks to LyX, the eps option occurs, because LyX is having trouble reading in my initial LaTeX(plain)? I am trying to get rid of all the image extensions (e.g. .png, .jpg) to see if I import this cleaner version to LyX, it no longer would produce fake images. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: Probably. But before of change your working document, make a  test with minimal documents to be sure of where is the problem (it should be enough some like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Hello \includegraphics[width=1cm]{myimage}
\end{document}`  and the same but with the extension)

Comment: Fran, I tried with a few images, and I get the following error message. I edited my post, so you can see the error messages from LyX. Where am I go wrong? Please help!

Comment: @FrankSwanton You have imported a document with a `\maketitle` but without defining a \title, and on the other hand, I cannot guess from here what are you doing wrongly with your images. Again, start only with the minimal document  of my above comment, and  instead of your images  use  [this uncorrupted true PNG image with a single extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkcmu.png). The import with LaTeX(palin)  should work now without problems, with or without adding the extension. Right?